# How to make clearInterval work at window resize in jquery?

Tags: jquery, animation, resize, clearinterval

I know this has been asked many times but I tried everything and still couldn't find the way through. Once the animation starts it can't be stopped resizing the browser. What's the correct way to do it? Thanks.

```
let x;

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    if ($(window).width() >= 980) {
        clearInterval(x);
    } else {
        x = setInterval(animation, 3000);
    }
});

function animation() {
    $('#media-container').delay(3000).animate({
        marginLeft: '-100%',
    }, 500).delay(3000).animate({
        marginLeft: '-200%',
    }, 500).delay(3000).animate({
        marginLeft: 0,
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: you should always call `clearInterval`. Otherwise any resize below 980 will enqueue a new interval and you will lose the reference to the others for good

Comment: @ffflabs Can you give an example? I'm new at this. Thank you very much for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved thanks to .stop(true, true):

```
setInterval(animation, 3000);

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    if ($(window).width() >= 980) {
        $('#media-container').stop(true, true);
        $('#media-container').animate({
            marginLeft: 0,
        });
        return;
    }
    animation();
})

function animation() {
    if ($(window).width() < 980) {
        $('#media-container').delay(3000).animate({
            marginLeft: '-100%',
        }, 500).delay(3000).animate({
            marginLeft: '-200%',
        }, 500).delay(3000).animate({
            marginLeft: 0,
        }, 500);
    }
}
```